# Trigger existing button with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, javascript, pdf-generation, itext

I am trying to automate filling out an existing PDF. The PDF's first page has buttons that display addenda if required. I can fill out the data on the first page fine. And I can see the fields that are in the hidden addenda, but when I put data in those fields the pages don't show automatically. When I click the buttons to show those pages, the data is not there.

Is there a way I can trigger the button events before filling in the addenda fields? Or is there some other work around to show the addenda pages as I require?

Comment: The simplest thing to do is to inspect the JavaScript and see what state's and/or appearances are being changed. Adobe Acrobat would be the easiest to inspect this, probably, although you could get to it from iText, too.

Comment: I think adobe has locked me out of seeing the Javascript for this particular pdf. I used iTextsharp and found lots of Javascript for deleting pages, but not the showing pages. I think maybe those scripts are indirectly referenced? and I couldn't figure out how to get to them.